# BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray sometimes returns null for same image

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-camera, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

I am trying to decode a byte array. The decodeByteArray returns NULL sometimes and sometimes it returns bitmap for the same image. I am calling this inside doInBackground. This is what I am doing:

```
 public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(byte[] data,
                                                        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);
    options.inScaled = true;
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    Bitmap bmpOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);
    return toGrayScale(bmpOriginal);
}
```

This behavior seems to be happening only on certain phones.

Comment: This may be caused by memory allocation. It looks like the image is too large for certain phones to properly decode the image. Have you checked your LogCat?

Comment: what should I be looking for in the logCat ?

Comment: For exceptions like(these are highlighted in red usually) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html

Comment: I don't see anything there

Comment: Does your app crash?

Comment: yes. It crashes. i Have added a unCaughtExceptionHandler

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89717/discussion-between-mike-and-rohit-ramkumar).